# Storing Eigen::Ref from numpy through pybind inside c++ fails

Tags: python, c++, eigen3, pybind11

I have a maybe stupid question concering storing a reference of a numpy object in a c++ class. I have the following MVE code:

```cpp
template<typename VecType= Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>>
struct A
{
  void insert(VecType& val)
  {
    std::cout<<"AddressOfValue: "<<val.data()<<std::endl;
    v.emplace(val);
    std::cout<<"AddressOfValueInserted: "<<v->get().data()<<std::endl;
  }

  VecType& get()
  {
    std::cout<<"AddressOfValueInGetter: "<<v->get().data()<<std::endl;
    return v->get();
  }
  
  std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<VecType>> v;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE( mod, m )
{
  auto lv2= pybind11::class_<A<>>(m, "A");
  lv2.def(pybind11::init());
  lv2.def( "insert", [] (A<>& req,  Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd> solVec ) { req.insert( solVec ); } );
  lv2.def( "get", [] (A<>& req ) { return req.get( ); } );
}
```

and the following python code

```py
a = mod.A()
d = np.zeros(10)
d[0] = 0.1
print('Python address: {}'.format(hex(d.__array_interface__['data'][0])))
a.insert(d)

print('Python addressAfter: {}'.format(hex(d.__array_interface__['data'][0])))
d2 = a.get()
print(len(d2))
print(d2[0])
print('Python addressAfterd: {}'.format(hex(d.__array_interface__['data'][0])))
print('Python addressAfterd2: {}'.format(hex(d2.__array_interface__['data'][0])))
```

If I execute this code i get

```py
1: AddressOfValue: 0x5607dccbdcd0
1: AddressOfValueInserted: 0x5607dccbdcd0
1: AddressOfValueInGetter: 0x7ffc258a654f
1: Python address: 0x5607dccbdcd0
1: Python addressAfter: 0x5607dccbdcd0
1: 94591762887704
1: 0.0
1: Python addressAfterd: 0x5607dccbdcd0
1: Python addressAfterd2: 0x7ffc258a654f
```

So basically I want to store the reference of my numpy array, which gets converted to a `Eigen::Ref<Matrix>` inside my
class.
The Python address and the adress of the Eigen::Ref match.
The addresses match even to the point after the value is inserted.

But If i use the getter I get some other uninitalized data and the address stops matching.
Maybe I misunderstood something fundamentely and there is a better way.
Can someone give me please a hint how to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use `std::reference_wrapper` for `Eigen::Ref`. If you only have `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>>`, I suggest to store a `double* ptr` and `Eigen::Index size` inside `A` and construct a `Map`/`Ref` on-the-fly when you need it.

Comment: Ah yes removing the std::reference_wrapper worked! Thanks!